# confused with layout resource file with layout xml file?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

during creating a fragment xml file(right clicking on layout folder in res) I am bit troubled with layout resource file with layout xml file ? and I am using Android Studio and also a newbie.
A little clarification might do the job !!

Comment: layout resource file is an xml file. Simply create a new layout resource file for your fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi add this line in your onCreateView() method of fragment:

```
@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_activity, container, false);
```

.....
and right click in layout folder and create xml file with name mentioned above.For example here it is fragment_main_activity.xml.

Comment: You should accept answer that solves the problem so that it helps future users